# What's the "inverse" function of export() in QMake?

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

In a QMake custom function, variables implicitly have local scope.  If you use the export() function you can create a global variable from one of these.

How do you do the inverse of that though?  I.e. "import" a global?

Further, how do you modify one? For instance, how do you update DEFINES from within a custom function?  If you edit a variable with that name inside a custom function (without this step that I'm missing) it's not really applied, because you just create and modify a local variable instead.

Comment: I am not really sure if I understand what you are talking about, but isnt a global already global? ie if it is global, then why would you need to import it?

Comment: The "export(var)" makes local to a function "var" available to context that was calling the function. It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I'm not sure how to be much more clear other than to post examples I guess.  In custom QMake functions "globals" are NOT visible.

Comment: `export(var)` makes a local variable available in the global context.  You can't get to the other globals however which have not been "imported".

Comment: `message(DEFINES)` inside a custom qmake function shows it has nothing there.  Editing DEFINES does nothing outside the function.  Globals in general are like that.

Comment: To be more clear, I'm talking about the use of `defineReplace()` or `defineTest()` which allows one to create thier own custom functions in QMake.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. When I want somefunction to modify DEFINES then I call it like DEFINES = $$somefunction(DEFINES). What indicates that there is some other way?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing too.  I'd like to avoid that.  Further, I'd like to be able to do something such as evaluate the contents of DEFINES or any other global from within a local context.  Nothing indicates that it is possible (other than the fact that it should be!), hence my question.

Answer (score 0):

qmake always imports all global variables into the local context, so no special directive needed. An example:

```
defineTest(myfunc) {
    myvar += three
    !build_pass:message("local myvar is" $$myvar) # prints 'one two three'
    return()
}

myvar = one two
myfunc()
!build_pass:message("global myvar is" $$myvar) # prints 'one two'
```